# How long will an AWS Lambda function stay loaded in memory without an active call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

We have data cached in our AWS lambda functions memory, and it would be very useful to know how long it will typically stay there before the function is removed for non-use on our development stages. Please note that I am talking specifically about the container data that may be reused. Please see: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

Answer (score 2):

Each invocation of a lambda function creates a unique instance of the function.  Even though the underlying container may persist for some unknown period of time for reuse (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction-function.html#topic3), it is not safe to assume that subsequent invocations will reuse a previous invocation's container with the expectation of data persistence.

If you load or create data in your lambda function that you need across calls, you need to write it to long-term storage, whether that's S3 or a database or something else.  You will need to reload any fetched data each time the function is invoked.

Edited to clarify container re-use.  Thanks to Rodrigo and Frederick Cheung for added links in comments.

Comment: Agreed, however containers *can* be reused, and not destroyed. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/.

Comment: @RodrigoM That blog post was written during the preview period.  Have they confirmed that that behavior didn't change?  At any rate, it sounds like even though the container is reused, that only applies to the files.  The code is still started fresh, so data cached in memory from a previous run is lost, and most importantly, 'Remember, you can’t depend on a container being reused, since it’s Lambda’s prerogative to create a new one instead.'

Comment: thanks yes I saw it was in preview then.  All current documentation seems to reference some reuse. But yes I would expect memory to be reset even with reuse,

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction-function.html#topic3 Specifically states that if a container is reused, in memory data is kept (the example they give is not having to re-establish a db connection on each invocation)

Comment: @FrederickCheung Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Also, if there are concurrent invocations, I can't see how they could avoid usign containers for each invocation, but I can't find that addressed explicitly.  But another argument for not assuming data persistence across invocations.

Comment: @KarenB - Thanks for the answer! My question was specifically about the timing on these containers and how they timeout. I have clarified the question. In my experience, the container gets unloaded at the same time as the function in the current implementation which is why the question was previous stated as the function being unloaded. I think it may be possible that multiple containers are available per machine. It will be interesting once we get into production to gauge container/req/sec.

Comment: @David I suppose it also matters why you're asking.  If you want to take advantage of that re-use, you could check to see if the container already has the data loaded, but you can't assume it.  If you want to protect against re-use with stale data, you'd also need to reload it in every run.  Some optimizations taking advantage may be viable but would have to be done with care.

Comment: @KarenB - We do check and we also expire data. The reason I was actually asking is that we flag if data has gotten so old that there was likely a fatal error with how it was refreshing. If I don't make this time really long, then on the dev environment, the time between requests could make this alarm go off. If I knew the time to flush, then I could set the "Error" time to be just a bit longer.